# Rails Multiple Databases with many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations, multiple-databases

I have models with many-to-many association for example User & Role which connected through RoleAssignment

table in DB1:

```
users
role_assignments
```

table in DB2:

```
roles
```

I can access user in DB1 with `role_one.users`, but i cannot access roles in DB2 with `user_one.roles`. It gives an exception

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'db2_development.role_assignments' doesn't exist: 
SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `role_assignments` ON `roles`.`id` = `role_assignments`.`role_id` 
WHERE `role_assignments`.`user_id` = 1
```

Does anyone know how to access roles from user, or how to let rails know that role_assignments reside in DB1 not in DB2? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem using `table_name_prefix` as shown at http://emphaticsolutions.com/2009/11/23/has_many_through_across_databases.html

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "app_name_development."
  end
end

class ExternalActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "external_development"

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "external_app_name_development."
  end
end
```

then

```
class Role< ExternalActiveRecord
  ...
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent done it myself, but you can subclass activerecord to maintain multiple db connections. See this blog post:

http://www.messaliberty.com/2009/02/ruby-how-to-use-multiple-databases-with-activerecord/

Comment: I have connected with multiple databases. Actually, i've already solved my quetion with [st-elsewhere](https://github.com/briandoll/st-elsewhere). Now i have a new problem, I try to connect User n Role with role_alias_assignments, i cannot access roles using alias for example: `has_many_elsewhere :role_aliases, source: :role, through: :role_alias_assignments`. it gives an error `undefined method `role_aliases' for #<User>`